# Apply function with multiple parameters and output variable

Tags: r, function

I am trying to apply a function with two arguments. The first argument is a dataframe, the second is an integer that defines a row of the df.

```
    col_1 <- c("A", "B", "C")
    col_2 <- c("red", "blue", "black")
    df <- data.frame(col_1, col_2)
    f <- function(x, arg1) {
      x[arg1, 1]
      x[arg1, 2]
    }
    apply(df, 1, f)
```

Looks like the second argument is not passed to the function. Here is the error

> Error in x[arg1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

when I put arg1=1 like this

```
apply(df, arg1=1, f)
```

it gives me a FUN error

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

the desired output is "A" and "red", i.e. in my real code I need to operate with the values of each row.

I also want to add an output variable to be able to save a plot that I am making in my real analysis in a file. Can I just add an "output" variable in function(x, arg1) and then do apply(df, arg1=1, f, output="output_file")?

Comment: Can I ask what precisely is the intended behavior of `f()`?  As it stands, `f()` itself will return only the value `x[arg1, 2]`: the value of the final statement in the function (in lieu of a `return()` statement). Furthermore, this seems to misuse the `apply()` function. If you want to simply subset rows and columns of your `df`, subscripting is the way to go: `df[1, ]` or `df[1, 1:2]` or `df[1, c("col_1", "col_2")]`; or more generally `df[vector_of_row_indices_or_names, vector_of_column_indices_or_names]`. In this

Comment: this particular function is supposed to return the values of the arg1 row. In my real analysis, the function makes more sense, it builds plot using values of each row. But this is where I have a problem, in getting those values. I am trying to understand why apply() doesn't pass arg1 or doesn't see function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Greg mentions, the purpose of this code isn't clear. However, the question seems to relate to how `apply()` works so here goes:

Basically, when any of the `apply` family of functions is used, the user-enetered function (`f()`, in this case) is applied to the subset of the data produced by `apply`. So here, you've asked `apply` to evaluate each row then call `f()` - the first argument to `f()` would then be a vector rather than the data frame your function requires.

Here's some functioning code:

```
col_1 <- c("A", "B", "C")
col_2 <- c("red", "blue", "black")
df <- data.frame(col_1, col_2)
f <- function(x) {
  x[1]
  x[2]
}
apply(df, 1, f)
```

This generates all of the values of the second column as a vector since x[2] is returned from the function and for each row, will represent the value in the second column.

If you want the `arg1` row of results, you could simply use the following:

```
find_row <- function(df, row) {
  df[row, ]
}
find_row(df, 1)
```

`apply()` isn't required. Using a single function makes the code simpler to read and should be faster too.

Comment: thank you for a thorough explanation. This is exactly what I was looking for